How to update a polars dataframe column at a specific range?
I want to update a specific column at a specific row index range.
Here's what I want to achieve in pandas:
df = pd.DataFrame({ "foo": [0,0,0,0] })
df["foo"].iloc[0:3] = 1
# or
df.iloc[0:3, df.columns.get_loc("foo")] = 1

How can I achieve this seemingly simple operation in polars? It seems to be possible to update a single row with the following:
df = pl.DataFrame({ "foo": [0,0,0,0] })
df[0, "foo"] = 1

but trying to update a range fails:
df[0:3, "foo"] = 1
# TypeError: cannot use "slice(0, 3, None)" for indexing

df[0:3]["foo"] = 1
# TypeError: DataFrame object does not support `Series` assignment by index

The recommended answer of using pl.when(pl.col("row_number").between(...)).then(...) adds a significant overhead that shouldn't be needed considering that the row number is sequential, ordered, and starting at 0. On a dataset with a million row, I'm seeing a 20x difference in performance between pandas df.iloc[...] = x and the current polars solution. Is there really no alternative ?

You typically wouldn't so this in polars, this is not working the same way as pandas (there is no index in polars). Also in pandas you would avoid using df["foo"].iloc[0:3] = 1 since it could trigger a SettingWithCopyWarning.

Polars dataframe do have an index, it is the row number. This is why you can write df[0] or df[0:2] in the first place. Their documentation explicitely says so in the "coming from Pandas section": "Polars does not use an index and each row is indexed by its integer position in the table.". Also, I specifically used iloc in my pandas example to show that I didn't care about the pandas-specific index.

I think slicing/appending may technically be "faster" than when/then: pl.col.foo.head(1).append(pl.lit(1).repeat_by(3).flatten()).append(pl.col.foo.slice(4)) - but still rather verbose.

After some testing, the fastest solution by far is to build the new column ourselves, by appending together the old values and the ones we want to update:
start, stop, value = 0, 3, -1

df = df.with_columns(
    foo=data[0 : start, "foo"]
    .append(pl.repeat(value, stop - start, eager=True, dtype=data["foo"].dtype))
    .append(data[stop : len(data), "foo"]),
)

However, it results in a series with 3 chunks, which might make further computations slower. All the other following solutions result in a uniquely chunked series, but are 10x slower.
Using scatter.
df = df.with_columns(df["foo"].scatter(range(start, stop), value))

Using extend instead of append:
df = df.with_columns(
    foo=data[0 : start, "foo"]
    .extend(pl.repeat(value, stop - start, eager=True, dtype=data["foo"].dtype))
    .extend(data[stop : len(data), "foo"]),
)

Using when
df = df.with_row_index().with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("index").is_between(start, stop))
    .then(value)
    .otherwise(pl.col("foo")),
)

Using update.
df = df.with_row_index().update(
    pl.select(
        pl.int_range(start, stop, dtype=pl.UInt32).alias("index"),
        pl.lit(value),
    ),
    on="index",
)


It may be worthwhile opening a performance issue for this. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues?q=pandas+label%3Aperformance They may consider it a "bug" that the recommended case has such a penalty.

Could you add your starting df and timings for your tests? Separate suggestion, you can use map_batches instead of using df["foo"] it'd be pl.col("foo").map_batches(lambda data: data[0 : start]     .append(pl.repeat(value, stop - start, eager=True, dtype=data.dtype))     .append(data[stop : len(data)])

@jqurious I don't think it's a bug. It's because arrow memory is immutable so anytime we're changing values we have to rewrite it all. The append approach side steps that but it's probably a long term footgun.

I think it's a neat trick that could be useful as long as there are no subsequent operations. I don't speak for team polars so don't take my thoughts as a sole reason to refrain from posting the issue.

Can you try concat in your benchmark? e.g. df.with_columns(pl.concat([pl.col("foo").slice(0, start), pl.repeat(value, stop - start), pl.col("foo").slice(stop)]))

concat also results, in a three-chunked series, it performs as well as the first (and fastest) option with append.

Ah - thanks. I guess that's the reason for speed, a lack of rechunking. Just tested .concat(..., rechunk=True) and it makes it 10x slower. (although still slightly faster than is_between)

If your dataframe has an index (as it can be added with pl.DataFrame.with_row_index), you can use a pl.when().otherwise() construct to selectively overwrite the values of a certain column.
(
    df
    .with_row_index()
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("index").is_between(1, 3)).then(1).otherwise("foo").name.keep()
    )
)

shape: (4, 2)
┌───────┬─────┐
│ index ┆ foo │
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ u32   ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ 0     ┆ 0   │
│ 1     ┆ 1   │
│ 2     ┆ 1   │
│ 3     ┆ 0   │
└───────┴─────┘

If you don't want to add an index to your dataframe, you can create it on-the-fly by using pl.int_range.
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(
        pl.int_range(pl.len()).is_between(1, 2)
    ).then(
        1
    ).otherwise(
        "foo"
    ).name.keep()
)

shape: (4, 1)
┌─────┐
│ foo │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 0   │
│ 1   │
│ 1   │
│ 0   │
└─────┘


No worries, I just learned you can just pass the column name to otherwise instead of pl.col('foo') :)
